# Symfony 2.6 login randomly fails

Tags: php, security, symfony

I'm starting a new Symfony2 project using it's latest stable release (2.6.1) and I've already set up a minimal login and security component configuration. However, half of the login attempts seem to fail after handling the /login_check request, when the user is redirected back to a homepage.

This is what the logs are showing after a failed login (arrows mine to emphasize):

```
request.INFO: Matched route "login_check" (parameters: "_route": "login_check") [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username AS username2, t0.password AS password3, t0.nombre AS nombre4, t0.apellidos AS apellidos5, t0.email AS email6, t0.movil AS movil7, t0.ciudad AS ciudad8, t0.hospital AS hospital9, t0.cargo AS cargo10, t0.roles AS roles11, t0.created_at AS created_at12 FROM usuarios t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1 ["admin"] []
--> security.INFO: User "admin" has been authenticated successfully [] []
security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
request.INFO: Matched route "homepage" (parameters: "_controller": "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction", "_route": "homepage") [] []
--> security.INFO: Populated SecurityContext with an anonymous Token [] []
security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

As you can see the login_check procedure actually succeeds in authenticating the user, but when it is redirected to another page the system somehow "forgets" it, as if it didn't actually store the result in the session. When the whole process works the log is looking like this:

```
request.INFO: Matched route "login_check" (parameters: "_route": "login_check") [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username AS username2, t0.password AS password3, t0.nombre AS nombre4, t0.apellidos AS apellidos5, t0.email AS email6, t0.movil AS movil7, t0.ciudad AS ciudad8, t0.hospital AS hospital9, t0.cargo AS cargo10, t0.roles AS roles11, t0.created_at AS created_at12 FROM usuarios t0 WHERE t0.username = ? LIMIT 1 ["admin"] []
--> security.INFO: User "admin" has been authenticated successfully [] []
security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
request.INFO: Matched route "homepage" (parameters: "_controller": "AppBundle\Controller\DefaultController::indexAction", "_route": "homepage") [] []
--> security.DEBUG: Read SecurityContext from the session [] []
security.DEBUG: Reloading user from user provider. [] []
doctrine.DEBUG: SELECT t0.id AS id1, t0.username AS username2, t0.password AS password3, t0.nombre AS nombre4, t0.apellidos AS apellidos5, t0.email AS email6, t0.movil AS movil7, t0.ciudad AS ciudad8, t0.hospital AS hospital9, t0.cargo AS cargo10, t0.roles AS roles11, t0.created_at AS created_at12 FROM usuarios t0 WHERE t0.id = ? [1] []
--> security.DEBUG: Username "admin" was reloaded from user provider. [] []
security.DEBUG: Write SecurityContext in the session [] []
```

This is the whole setup I have at the moment. I'd wager it's either a misconfiguration in the security.yml file or a bug (?), but I don't know where else to look.

security.yml

```
security:
    encoders:
        AppBundle\Entity\Usuario: bcrypt

    role_hierarchy:
        ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
        ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ROLE_USER, ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH]

    providers:
        usuarios:
            entity: { class: AppBundle\Entity\Usuario, property: username }

    firewalls:
        dev:
            pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
            security: false

        default:
            pattern: ^/
            anonymous: ~
            form_login:
                check_path: login_check
                login_path: login
            logout:
                path:   logout
                target: homepage

    access_control:
        - { path: ^/$,      roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/login$, roles: IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY }
        - { path: ^/.*,     roles: ROLE_USER }
```

routing.yml

```
app:
    resource: @AppBundle/Controller/
    type:     annotation

login_check:
    path: /login_check

logout:
    path: /logout
```

login.html.twig

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    {% if error %}
        <div>{{ error.message }}</div>
    {% endif %}

    <form action="{{ path('login_check') }}" method="post">
        <label for="username">Nombre de usuario:</label>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="_username" value="{{ last_username }}" />
        <label for="password">Contraseña:</label>
        <input type="password" id="password" name="_password" />
        <input type="submit" name="login" value="Acceder" />
    </form>
{% endblock %}
```

DefaultController.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        // Symfony dummy template that just shows 'Homepage.'
        return $this->render('default/index.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/login", name="login")
     */
    public function loginAction()
    {
        $authUtils = $this->get('security.authentication_utils');

        return $this->render('login/index.html.twig', array(
            'last_username' => $authUtils->getLastUsername(),
            'error'         => $authUtils->getLastAuthenticationError(),
        ));
    }
}
```

Usuario.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\AdvancedUserInterface;

/**
 * @ORM\Table(name="usuarios")
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Usuario implements AdvancedUserInterface
{
    const ROLE_USER = 'ROLE_USER';
    const ROLE_ADMIN = 'ROLE_ADMIN';

    /**
     * @var integer
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="username", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $username;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="password", type="string", length=60)
     */
    private $password;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="nombre", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $nombre;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="apellidos", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $apellidos;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="email", type="string", length=255, unique=true)
     */
    private $email;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="movil", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $movil;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="ciudad", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $ciudad;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="hospital", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $hospital;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="cargo", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $cargo;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="roles", type="simple_array", length=255)
     */
    private $roles;

    /**
     * @var \DateTime
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="created_at", type="datetime")
     */
    private $createdAt;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->roles = [self::ROLE_USER];
        $this->createdAt = new \DateTime();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    // ... An awful lot of generic getters and setters

    // Plus the mandatory AdvancedUserInterface methods:
    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->username;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getPassword()
    {
        return $this->password;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function isAccountNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function isAccountNonLocked()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function isCredentialsNonExpired()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function isEnabled()
    {
        return true;
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function getSalt()
    {
        return null;    // I'm using the bcrypt encoder
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function eraseCredentials()
    {
        $this->password = null;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, this was a subtle one. I didn't mention that I'm also using the PDOSessionHandler to store the sessions in a database, and this proved to be the root of the problem.

Up until now I used to add a custom Session class to the `Entity` namespace of my main bundle in order to generate the sessions table alongside the others whenever I ran `console doctrine:schema:create`. Apparently this table's mandatory schema has been modified as of the 2.6 release and my entity no longer matched it.

https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/12833

Fortunately I've also learned that the PDOSessionHandler class has a helper method called `createTable()` which does exactly this, and since you must define it as a service anyway I decided to drop the entity approach and start using a Command to leverage this method. With this new schema the login procedure now always works. Here's all the relevant code and configurations:

config.yml

```
framework:
    session:
        handler_id:  session.handler.pdo

services:
    pdo:
        class: PDO
        arguments:
            - "mysql:host=%database_host%;port=%database_port%;dbname=%database_name%"
            - "%database_user%"
            - "%database_password%"
        calls:
            - [setAttribute, [3, 2]] # \PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, \PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION

    session.handler.pdo:
        class:     Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Storage\Handler\PdoSessionHandler
        arguments: ["@pdo"]
```

SetupSessionsTableCommand.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Command;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\ContainerAwareCommand;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Input\InputInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Console\Output\OutputInterface;

/**
 * This command leverages the PdoSessionHandler::createTable()
 * method from the session.handler.pdo service.
 */
class SetupSessionsTableCommand extends ContainerAwareCommand
{
    protected function configure()
    {
        $this
            ->setName('setup:sessions')
            ->setDescription('Creates the sessions table');
    }

    protected function execute(InputInterface $input, OutputInterface $output)
    {
        $sessionHandler = $this->getContainer()->get('session.handler.pdo');

        try {
            $sessionHandler->createTable();
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            $output->writeln("<error>Exception thrown while attempting to create the 'sessions' table</error>");
            $output->writeln($e->getMessage());
            $output->writeln($e->getTraceAsString());

            return -1;
        }

        $output->writeln("<info>'sessions' table created successfully</info>");

        return 0;
    }
}
```